# How can I instantiate a inner public static final class in java from a different package

Tags: java, unit-testing, oop, mocking

I have a use case where I am trying to instantiate an inner public static final class from a different package. I am trying to do this so that I can mock the Response to unit testing. We can use a mock server, however, I just want to use a mock object for this case for speed and more controlled testing. Here is the code snippet below:

```
public class Http {
  private final HttpClient client;

  @Inject
  Http(HttpClient client) {
    this.client = client;
  }

  public Http.Response get(Http.Request request) {
    try {
      Http.Response response = this.getResponse(this.client.execute(this.createHttpGet(request)));
      return response;
    } catch (IOException var4) {
      throw new RuntimeException(var4);
    } catch (URISyntaxException var5) {
      throw new RuntimeException(var5);
    }
  }

  private Http.Response getResponse(HttpResponse httpResponse) throws IOException {
    Http.Response response = new Http.Response(httpResponse.getStatusLine().getStatusCode());
    response.setMessageBody(EntityUtils.toString(httpResponse.getEntity()));
    return response;
  }

  public static final class Response {
    private final int statusCode;
    private ImmutableMap<String, String> headers;
    private String message;
    private String messageBody;

    Response(int statusCode) {
      this.statusCode = statusCode;
    }

    public int getStatusCode() {
      return this.statusCode;
    }

    public Map<String, String> getHeaders() {
      return this.headers;
    }

    void setHeaders(Map<String, String> headers) {
      this.headers = ImmutableMap.builder().putAll(headers).build();
    }

    public String getMessage() {
      return this.message;
    }

    void setMessage(String message) {
      this.message = message;
    }

    public String getMessageBody() {
      return this.messageBody;
    }

    void setMessageBody(String messageBody) {
      this.messageBody = messageBody;
    }

    public String toString() {
      return String.format("HttpResponse{statusCode=%d, headers=%s, message='%s', messageBody='%s'}", this.statusCode, this.headers, this.message, this.messageBody);
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `Http.Response` constructor needs to be public to be instantiated from another package.

Here, because its visibility is `default`, you can only instantiate it from the same package.

You seem to need it for testing purposes. If you don't want to change the visibility, you can create a class in your testing classes in the same package as your `Http` class only for instantiating `Responses`.